# Run-time error 1004 dissapear after hand writing

Tags: excel, weekday

I have a macro to fill some cells with values. Then I have a macro for picking these values and make some worksheet function. If I cell `BUNKA_issue_om_date` fill by handwriting, macro runs well. But if I use first part for writing a date into that cell, the macro crashes with 1004 on worksheet function `Weekday`.

First part:

```
Sub SKRIPT_issue_om_f1()
Range("BUNKA_issue_om_date").Value = Format$(Now, "dd.mm.yyyy")
Range("BUNKA_issue_om_time").Value = Format$(Now, "h:mm")
Range("BUNKA_issue_om_filtr").Value = "F1"
End Sub
```

Second part:

```
    Sub SKRIPT_issue_om_save()

    PROM_issue_om_date = Range("BUNKA_issue_om_date")
    PROM_issue_om_time = Range("BUNKA_issue_om_time")
    PROM_issue_om_filtr = Range("BUNKA_issue_om_filtr")

    PROM_Day = WorksheetFunction.Weekday(Range("BUNKA_issue_om_date"), vbMonday)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format function produces a string not a date. You need to either convert that string to a date in your second part, or enter the data as a date in the first part. So either

```
 With Range("BUNKA_issue_om_date")
       .Value = NOW()
       'NumberFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY"
 End With
```

OR

```
   PROM_issue_om_date = CDate(Range("BUNKA_issue_om_date"))
```

Comment: Thank you. Works well of course. My unknowledge about output type here.